# Not able to install the Prometheus metrics plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, prometheus

I am trying to install the Prometheus plugin. But I'm getting this plugin. I tried reinstalling Jenkins once again and tried but to no avail. The error is as below. I am not facing any issues with other plugins though.
[image]

Comment: This version has been released 7 hour ago, maybe it hasn't propagated to all the mirrors yet. You can install manually from https://ci.jenkins.io/job/Plugins/job/prometheus-plugin/job/master/381/

Comment: Yeah, I tried one version older than the current one. I installed it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I installed one version older manually. This solved the problem for me.